# Check if simple graph is oriented?

Tags: java

The Task is

> "You've got a adjacency matrix (nxn). And simple graph. Print YES, if the graph is undirected and NO otherwise."

My teacher says that the programm is incorrect. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Graph {

    private static Scanner scan;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int n = scan.nextInt();

        Graph graph = new Graph();
        int[][] matrix = graph.createMatrix(n);
        boolean truth = graph.checkoriented(matrix);
        System.out.println((truth)? "Yes": "No");

        scan.close();
    }

    private boolean checkoriented(int[][] matrix) {
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
                if(matrix[i][j] == 1){                  //look if  element on i pow, j column is "1";
                    boolean way = (matrix[j][i] == 1)? true: false; //if element on j pow i locumn is 1 also 
                    if(!way) return false;          // if element on j pow i locumn is 0 graph is oriented
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private int[][] createMatrix(int n) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: `boolean way = (matrix[j][i] == 1)? true: false;` could be simplified to `boolean way = matrix[j][i] == 1;`. Also if you are to check whether a graph is directed or not I'd keep that terminology, i.e. `checkoriented()` might be a confusing name (is oriented = directed or undirected in your opinion? `boolean truth = graph.checkoriented(matrix);` it means undirected ).

Comment: Oops, thx! I didn't know it!)

Comment: @VladokAC can you show desired results? As in, can you show when the program should print 'Yes' and when 'No' with examples?

Comment: @PravinSonawane Examples on the site: Input example #1
3
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
Output example #1
YES;                             Input example #2
3
0 1 1
1 0 1
0 1 0
Output example #2
NO;            My results absolutely match with sites result. (I fixed "Yes" to "YES", and "No" to "NO". however, it doesnt help)

Comment: You could change your check method to only do `if( matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) return false;` which should be sufficient. If it still doesn't work also check whether you're reading the matrix correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is actually a problem, but if your output should be `YES` or `NO` you'd better print these instead of `Yes` and  `No` here `System.out.println((truth)? "Yes": "No");`.
P. S. If your graph has a way from the vertex to the same one (I mean `matrix[i][i] = 1`), your algorithm might consider the graph to be undirected, while it is not.

Comment: Yep! I thought if the graph is simple by the task condition, it has only "0" on the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, I've correct as You told me. Now It works absolutely ideally.

Comment: @VladokAC - Glad for you

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion and A. Yurchenko's inputs, I'm updating my answer for completeness (only).

```
private boolean checkoriented(int[][] matrix) {

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
            if(i == j && matrix[i][j] !=0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've chaged the code at the same as yours. However, the checker program says "only 78 / 100 % ". Also, it cannot show numerals when my programm work incorrectly.

Comment: Hmm.. seems there is more to it. This program does work for the two examples you shared with me. It would be helpful if you can share more examples. Meanwhile, I will search the net for better understanding myself.

Comment: I will be obliged if U find the decision. Also, I can send the web site with this task to You.

Comment: @VladokAC yes please share the link here.

Comment: I added the line "if(matrix[i][i] != 0)return false;" by A. Yurchenko advice. Now programm works ideally. Anyway, thx very much for your help.

Comment: Glad it works. I will add A. Yurchenko's input to my answer here for completeness (You should accept his answer as that has worked for you)